# IdentityServer Tutorial , token has Invalid Signature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver3

I created a test application with the identity server.

It is very simple. it has some hard coded InMemory Users,Clients and SCopes and uses the idsrv3test.pfx certificated from the samples for signing

```
var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
factory
    .UseInMemoryUsers(MemoryUsers.All())
    .UseInMemoryClients(MemoryUsers.GetClients())
    .UseInMemoryScopes(MemoryUsers.GetScopes());

var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"..\certs\idsrv3test.pfx", "idsrv3test");

var options = new IdentityServerOptions()
{
    Factory = factory,
    EnableWelcomePage = true,
    SigningCertificate = cert,
    RequireSsl = false
};
 app.UseIdentityServer(options);
```

Now I get a a token via the **connect/token** endpoint. as grant type I use password.

This succeeds and I got a bearer token back.

now I wanted to validated the token contents on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) . I shows me all the informations of all parts of the token. but at the end of the site it shows me "invalid signature"

[image]

Is this the result of a bug ? Or just a result that I use this test certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jwt.io cannot validate RS256 signatures. Only HS256.

Comment: Ah thx. your right! I didn't read that . there is a small comment about that on the page i've overseen

Comment: As of 2018, jwt.io does support verifying RS256 signatures